# Table with multiple panels, with caption and notes. How to place the caption on top of the table and notes below?

Tags: tables, captions, subcaption

I have a table with multiple panels. I use the subtable package for to get the panels. My question is how could I place the caption for the overall table (the description of the entire table) on top? And then notes at the bottom?  The sample code is below. The other packages I use are

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
   \usepackage{rotating}
   \usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage{float}
   \restylefloat{table}
   \usepackage{subcaption}
   \usepackage{tabularx} % for better tables
   \usepackage{booktabs}



    \begin{document}

     \begin{table}
     \centering
     \caption{This table shows the details}
     \begin{subtable}[t]{\linewidth}
     \centering
     \vspace{0pt}
     \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} lccc} 
     \toprule 
     \toprule
          Year & $2002$ & $2003$ & $2004$ \\ 
          \midrule
           model1 & $1.703$ & $1.339$ & $1.238$  \\ 
           model2 & $2.104$ & $1.920$ & $1.774$  \\ 
        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular} 
     \caption{Panel A: One year ahead}
     \vspace{0.7cm}

     \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} lccc} 
     \toprule 
     \toprule
           Year & $2002$ & $2003$ & $2004$ \\ 
           \midrule
            model1 & $1.703$ & $1.339$ & $1.238$  \\ 
            model2 & $2.104$ & $1.920$ & $1.774$  \\ 
           \bottomrule
       \end{tabular} 
      \caption{Panel B: Two year ahead}
    \end{subtable}\hfill
 \end{table}

      \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: @Andrew Edited the code now.

Comment: Shouldn't you have 2 `subtable` environments rather than just one?

Comment: `\restylefloat{table}` moves the caption below the table. Just delete it to restore the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\restylefloat{table}` causes the caption to be moved below the tables. Simply remove it to prevent this.

Double rules are really neither necessary nor appropriate: `\toprule` is already heavy to mark the boundary and doubling it just looks cluttered.

Also, you surely want a `subtable` environment per panel and not one containing both. At least, I assume.

I've removed some packages irrelevant to your example as they don't belong in an MWE, but you can obviously restore them if you need them in your real document.

I've left `float` just to show that it is not the package itself which causes the change.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}    
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{This table shows the details}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \vspace{0pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} lccc}
      \toprule
      Year & $2002$ & $2003$ & $2004$ \\
      \midrule
      model1 & $1.703$ & $1.339$ & $1.238$  \\
      model2 & $2.104$ & $1.920$ & $1.774$  \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Panel A: One year ahead}
  \end{subtable}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} lccc}
      \toprule
      Year & $2002$ & $2003$ & $2004$ \\
      \midrule
      model1 & $1.703$ & $1.339$ & $1.238$  \\
      model2 & $2.104$ & $1.920$ & $1.774$  \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Panel B: Two year ahead}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: 2 subtables with caption above]

Comment: Works great. How about the other part of my question -- notes on the bottom of the table? Is that a possibility?

Comment: @rajvijay To be honest, I don't really know what you mean. Which table needs the notes? I'd use `threeparttable` or `threeparttablex`. But it is hard to tell without more information.